# The Fredholm Alternative

Tags: linear-algebra

Use Fredholm alternative to derive conditions on $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ that are required for $Ax=b$ to have a solution where $A = \{a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4\}$ where $a_1=[1,-3,7]$, $a_2=[2,1,0]$, $a_3=[4,-3,10]$, and $a_4=[-2,2,-6]$.

Can someone explain to me, as simply as possible, the Fredholm alternative so that I can give this problem a shot? The problem is that I have no idea what it is asking. Thank you!

Comment: Fredholm alternative in this context means that $b$ is either in the image of $A$ or not. Since "being in the image of $A$" means "being orthogonal to the kernel of $A^T$", equivalently, either $Ax=b$ has a solution or there is a solution to $A^Ty=0$ with $y^Tb\neq 0$. So the question asks you to find conditions on $b$ so that all solutions to $A^Ty=0$ are orthogonal to $b$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel, you can replace the $y^Tb \neq 0$ by $y^Tb = 1$

Comment: you have asked 29 questions and have not accepted/voted once!